Indirect function to link external worksheet
I have the following issue, I try to make a formula to refer to an external excel file based on the date. When try format the date to ddmmyy and use it in this formula I get a #ref error.
=IFERROR(COUNTIFS('R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\[230924.xlsx]Data'!$V$2:$V$999;
">=01/01/1970  22:00:00";'R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\[230924.xlsx]Data'!$A$2:$A$999;"LA")
+COUNTIFS('R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\[240924.xlsx]Data'!$V$2:$V$999;
"<=01/01/1970  06:00:00";'R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\[240924.xlsx]Data'!$A$2:$A$999;"LA");"")


This formula works, but when i try to use indirect to make the path a variable i get the error.
Edit:
The countifs i got working by opening the external workbooks with VBA
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Cursor = xlWait
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\180924.xlsx")
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\190924.xlsx")
wkb.Close (False)
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\200924.xlsx")
wkb2.Close (False)
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\210924.xlsx")
wkb.Close (False)
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\220924.xlsx")
wkb2.Close (False)
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\230924.xlsx")
wkb.Close (False)
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\240924.xlsx")
wkb2.Close (False)
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\250924.xlsx")
wkb.Close (False)
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\260924.xlsx")
wkb2.Close (False)
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\270924.xlsx")
wkb.Close (False)
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\280924.xlsx")
wkb2.Close (False)
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\290924.xlsx")
wkb.Close (False)
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("R:\hal 6\nicarm\LijstenPerDagExcel\300924.xlsx")
wkb2.Close (False)
wkb.Close (False)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
End Sub

It is very basic I should use a loop to go through the workbooks but I used this as a placeholder.

INDIRECT is volatile and volatile functions require the target workbook to be open.  For dynamic variable you will need vba to create the static formula, but I still think the vba will need to open the workbook to create the link then close it.

COUNTIFS doesn't work with a closed workbook anyway.
